# Nginx 1.6 конфиг для Yii2 advanced

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

Здравствуйте. У меня следующая проблема:

Я создал сайт на Yii2 advanced используя Apache и следующий .htaccess

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin\/?(.*) /backend/web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|admin)
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php
```

Но тепер, мне нужно мой сайт перенести на nginx 1.6.
Я нашол вот такой конфиг файл

```
server {
    listen         %ip%:%httpport%;
    listen         %ip%:%httpsport% ssl;
    server_name    %host% %aliases%;
    # if ($request_method !~* ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ){return 403;}
    location ~ /\. {deny all;}


location / {
    root       "%hostdir%/frontend/web";
    index      index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
    root                               "%hostdir%/frontend/web";
    try_files                          $uri =404;
    # if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}
    fastcgi_pass                       backend;
    fastcgi_index                      index.php;
    fastcgi_buffers                    4 64k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout            1s;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort        off;
    fastcgi_next_upstream              timeout;
    fastcgi_read_timeout               5m;
    fastcgi_send_timeout               5m;
    fastcgi_param    CONTENT_TYPE      $content_type;
    fastcgi_param    CONTENT_LENGTH    $content_length;
    fastcgi_param    DOCUMENT_URI      $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param    DOCUMENT_ROOT     $document_root;
    fastcgi_param    GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param    HTTPS             $https;
    fastcgi_param    QUERY_STRING      $query_string;
    fastcgi_param    REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;
    fastcgi_param    REQUEST_URI       $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param    REMOTE_ADDR       $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param    REMOTE_PORT       $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param    SERVER_ADDR       $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param    SERVER_PORT       $server_port;
    fastcgi_param    SERVER_NAME       $host;
    fastcgi_param    SERVER_PROTOCOL   $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param    SERVER_SOFTWARE   nginx;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_NAME       $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param    TMP               "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
    fastcgi_param    TMPDIR            "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
    fastcgi_param    TEMP              "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
}


location /openserver/ {
    root     "%sprogdir%/modules/system/html";
    index    index.php;
    %allow%allow    all;
    allow    127.0.0.0/8;
    allow    ::1/128;
    allow    %ips%;
    deny     all;
    location /openserver/server-status {
        stub_status on;
    }
    location ~ ^/openserver/.*\.php$ {
        root                               "%sprogdir%/modules/system/html";
        fastcgi_pass                       backend;
        fastcgi_index                      index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers                    4 64k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout            1s;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort        off;
        fastcgi_next_upstream              timeout;
        fastcgi_read_timeout               5m;
        fastcgi_send_timeout               5m;
        fastcgi_param    CONTENT_TYPE      $content_type;
        fastcgi_param    CONTENT_LENGTH    $content_length;
        fastcgi_param    DOCUMENT_URI      $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param    DOCUMENT_ROOT     $document_root;
        fastcgi_param    GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param    HTTPS             $https;
        fastcgi_param    QUERY_STRING      $query_string;
        fastcgi_param    REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;
        fastcgi_param    REQUEST_URI       $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param    REMOTE_ADDR       $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param    REMOTE_PORT       $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param    SERVER_ADDR       $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param    SERVER_PORT       $server_port;
        fastcgi_param    SERVER_NAME       $host;
        fastcgi_param    SERVER_PROTOCOL   $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param    SERVER_SOFTWARE   nginx;
        fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_NAME       $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param    TMP               "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
        fastcgi_param    TMPDIR            "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
        fastcgi_param    TEMP              "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
    }
}

}
```

Но работает только frontend, подскажите как сделать чтобы backend был доступен по ссылке /admin .
Спасибо.

P.S. Я работаю на Openserver. С nginx не работал никогда.

Comment: лучше погуглите и напишите что-то сами, а мы тут поможем написанное довести до ума

Comment: @norbornen, я уточнил вопрос

Comment: Конвертните ReWrite-правила для /admin при помощи конвертора, например, этого http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/

Comment: @Тарас, молодец. Теперь смотри, в том конфиге, который ты прикрепил есть такие конструкции как %hostdir%, %sprogdir% и т.п., и, наверное, в том месте, где ты его взял были рекомендации про то, что нужно подставить на их места. Подставь. Проверь и проверь. Далее. В конфиге написано `fastcgi_pass backend;`, но нет такого апстрима - значит нужно посмотреть что именно писали всё в тех же рекомендациях, добавить секцию upstream и приписать там параметры коннекта к твоему бекенду. Должно получится.

Comment: @norbornen, а что указывать вместо %host% %aliases% и  %allow%?

Comment: @norbornen, в рекомендациях не упоминаеться о upstream

Comment: @Тарас имя хоста, альтернативные имена хоста, ip-адреса с которых будет доступ к openserver.

Comment: @Тарас вместо "backend" нужно поставить что-то про то как ты коннектишься к бекенду. например `127.0.0.1:9000` или `unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`

Comment: на мой взгляд человека никак не связанного с yii2 вот тут более осмысленный конфиг https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md#preparing-application

Comment: @norborned, возможно, но у меня с этим конфигом сервер даже не запускаеться (